# R: One-sided T-Test of already calculated Correlations

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation

I have the following problem. For the data of my within-subject design, I calculated the correlation between two variables on the level of every participant. I used a code like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Correlation <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(
    var01_02 = cor(value_01, value_02, method = "pearson")
    )
View(Correlation)
```

My output is a table of correlations between two variables for every participant:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID value01_02
01 0.765
02 0.63
03 0.773
04 0.599
05 0.679
06 0.67
07 0.728
08 0.589
09 0.699', header=TRUE)
```

After I conducted a correlation analyses at the level of individual participants I would like to run significance tests on these resulting correlations using one-sided t-tests against zero.

Does anyone has an idea how I should approach this? What would be the next step? Thank you in advance!